# String compare in c with fgets

Tags: c

this is just a simple code i just wrote and i dont understand why it wont give me true when i type mother in the stream. It's logical for me when they compare each other it must be the same or?
this is my simple code:

```
 char string[20];
 fgets(string,20,stdin);

 printf("%s",string);

 if(strcmp(string,"mother")==0)
 {
   printf("they are the same");
 }
 else
 {
     printf("they are not");
 }
```

i also tried with

```
 if(string =="mother")
 \\do something
```

but it wont just give me true can someone help me

Comment: `fgets` does not compare strings. For `strcmp` it does not matter **how** the strings are created. And what about the documentation of the functions don't you understand?

Comment: Try `printf("<%s>\n",string);` to see what you are reading with `fgets()`.

Comment: `strcmp(string,"mother\n")`

Answer (score 3):

```
 if(string =="mother")  // won't work
```

You can't compare C strings directly with `==`. Use standard library function `strcmp` instead

```
if( 0 == strcmp(string, "mother") )
{
    printf( "equal" );
}
```

Also you would need to remove `\n` from `fgets`, otherwise the string comparison deems to false.

```
fgets(string,20,stdin);
string[strcspn(string, "\n")] = 0;   // without this, `strcmp` would return false
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you can't compare strings with `==`. In order for your code to work, you need to strip the `\n` character appended from `fgets()`. Otherwise you are comparing:

```
if (strcmp("mother\n", "mother") == 0) {
```

Which will always be false, unless you remove the `\n` character.

Since `fgets()` returns `NULL` if unsuccessful when reading input from the user, it is also safe to check that, like this:

```
if (fgets(string, 20, stdin) == NULL) {
    /* Exit program */
}
```

You can also add some extra error checking for `fgets()`, such as checking for buffer overflow, which can be checked like this:

```
slen = strlen(string);
if (slen > 0) {
    if (string[slen-1] == '\n') {
        string[slen-1] = '\0';
    } else {
        /* Exit program */
    }
}
```

After these considerations, your code can possibly look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 20

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char string[BUFFSIZE];
    size_t slen;
    const char *compare = "mother";

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    if (fgets(string, BUFFSIZE, stdin) == NULL) {
        printf("Error reading string into buffer.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    slen = strlen(string);
    if (slen > 0) {
        if (string[slen-1] == '\n') {
            string[slen-1] = '\0';
        } else {
            printf("Buffer overflow. Exceeded buffer size of %d.\n", BUFFSIZE);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    } 

    if (!*string) {
        printf("No string entered.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("My string = %s.\n", string);
    if (strcmp(string, compare) == 0) {
        printf("They are the same.\n");
    } else {
        printf("They are not the same.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` does not remove the new-line (`\n`) from the input. You should remove it (if present) before comparing the strings:

```
char string[20];
fgets(string,20,stdin);

int len = strlen(string);
// len-1 is the last character before the original \0
if(len > 0 && string[len-1] == '\n'){
    // remove the new-line by ending the string sooner
    string[len-1] = '\0';
}

if(strcmp(string,"mother")==0)
```

Your second attempt, comparing two strings using `==` directly will definitely not work.

Comment: Suggest `if(len > 1` --> `if(len > 0`

Answer (score 0):

From the man page for `fgets()`:

```
fgets()  reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and
stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading  stops  after  an
EOF  or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.
A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the  last  character  in
the buffer.
```

Have you checked if there is a newline character appended to your input?  `"mother"` is not the same as `"mother\n"`.