# my true or false if else statement isn't working

Tags: c

I am coding something and this should print "Good Job" but instead it is just saying "invalid lol,".

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

fgets(line, 69, stdin);
if (strcmp(line, "stats") == 0)
   {
       printf("Good Job\n");
   }
else
   {
       printf("Invalidlol\n");
   {
```

Comment: See [mcve].....

Comment: Echoing what @user3386109 said, this is not a valid program as it does not have a `main` function.  Also, what did you type in as the input?

Comment: Note that the string returned by `fgets` *includes* the trailing newline character. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/10871073

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String compare in c with fgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41252808/string-compare-in-c-with-fgets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the newline is getting added to your string. Try

> if (strcmp(line, "stats\n") == 0)

For a quick fix